# WriteToFile: How to write multiple data in a csv (or any) file?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, csv

I am trying to save users name and email in a csv file. There will be less than 50 people who will enter their name and email into this app. These details should be stored in a csv file and I must be able to physically access the file in the iPad. Please help!!

Comment: Start with http://whathaveyoutried.com/

Answer (score 4):

So we need to first understand the format of a csv file. It's pretty easy actually, it is only  a file where data is separated by commas and line breaks.

So say we need to store peoples' name, email, and a message. A csv file would like this:

John Doe, john@abc.com, Hello World!

Jane Doe, jane@abc.com, Foo Foo

Here we have two people separated by line breaks and their info separated by commas. We will need an `outputString` to hold all of this mess.

So now lets say we have an array of people called `peopleArray`. Our `peopleArray` holds a bunch of `PeopleObjects` and each `PeopleObject` has a `name`, `email`, and `message` property.

We have a nice big array of people and their respective information. Now lets create our `outputString`.

```
NSString *outputString = @"";

for (PeopleObject *person in peopleArray) {
       outputString = [outputString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@,%@,%@\n", person.name, person.email, person.message];
}
```

This will create the properly formatted string. So now we need to write all this to a file.

We will first need the documents directory:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Now `docDirectory` will tell us where to write the file. Next we need to append a file name to the directory.

```
NSString *outputFileName = [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"People.csv"];
```

So now we have our formatted csv string and a location to save it to. Last part is to write it out to a file.

```
//Create an error incase something goes wrong
NSError *csvError = NULL;

//We write the string to a file and assign it's return to a boolean
BOOL written = [outputString writeToFile:outputFileName atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&csvError];

//If there was a problem saving we show the error if not show success and file path
if (!written) 
    NSLog(@"write failed, error=%@", csvError);
else
    NSLog(@"Saved! File path =", outputFileName);
```

Now if you need to access the file again just save the `outputFileName` so you'll know where it is.

Comment: Hi Mr. Cory, Thanks a lot for the reply.. Now I am able to save the csv file... So I am using two textfields to get the details from the user.... So I am not using for loop... instead I am directly sending the values to output string... But instead of appending, its getting overwrite and replaces with the new data. I use outputString = [outputString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@,%@\n", name.text, address.text]; 
and
BOOL written = [outputString writeToFile:outputfilename atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&csverror];

Comment: Since you are not using the for loop make sure and declare outputString in your header file. Initialize it in your viewDidLoad and then you will be able to append to it.

Comment: Ok.... I got it to work... thanks a lot for your help... A final question... So in my mac book pro, the people.csv file is stored in Documents directory of Apps. Lets say if I deploy this app in an iPad, where should I go to get this file? I want to be able to go to that folder in iPad and delete the csv file or copy that file to drop box or mac book... Can you help me out?

Comment: The full path to your file is outputFileName. The only way you can delete it on the iPad is to implement that functionality in your app. Which if you know the file path then it's trivial to do. To upload to dropBox you will need to implement their api in your app. To get to your mac book take a look at this example: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app

Comment: Hi Mr. Cory, 
0down votefavorite

 



I have already implemented an app for iPad as Single View Application (Portrait). After deploying that in iPad, when I turn the ipad to landscape, the app also turns but the text fields are not visible. How can I implement scrolling for this problem? Its for iOS5